# Set::Object with type constraint checking

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to extend Set::Object in order to allow type constraint checking when inserting objects. My class so far looks like this:

```
package My::Set::Object;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
extends 'Set::Object';

has type => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);

before [ qw(insert invert intersection union) ] => sub {
my ($self,$list) = @_;

for (@$list) {
    confess "Only ",$self->type," objects are allowed " unless $_->does($self->type);
}
};

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

Unfortunately, it appears that the construction arguments are passed through to Set::Object as well when i do the following example object construction

```
my $set = My::Set::Object->new(type => 'Foo::Bar');
```

After printing out the contents of set, i find that "type" and "Foo::Bar" are members of the set.

How can i fix this? Or is there perhaps an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Don't extend the class. Give the moose class a Set::Object accessor that initializes a Set::Object and 'handles' the methods, then wrap them like you currently are. Edit: See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Types::Set::Object

Comment: Agree with Oesor, the composition with handles is better approach. You cannot prevent parent seeing your attributes this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, as an actual answer. I usually code along these lines and should do what you need. Warning: I haven't tested this code, it may not even compile, but it should get you on the right track. The only real difference with this vs subclassing is ->ISA on your My::Set::Object objects is not going to be true when checking for 'Set::Object'.

```
package My::Set::Object;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use Set::Object;

my @methods = qw/insert includes has contains invert intersection union/; # etc etc.

has type => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
has _so => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Set::Object', handles => \@methods, lazy_build => 1);

before [ qw(insert invert intersection union) ] => sub {
  my ($self,$list) = @_;

  for (@$list) {
    confess "Only ",$self->type," objects are allowed " unless $_->does($self->type);
  }
};

sub _build__so {
  return Set::Object->new()
}
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

Comment: Also note that making list of methods is not necessary, you can handle every method matching regex like `handles => qr/^[a-z]/`

Comment: Or more sanely use a `duck_type` in both the delegate and the type check.

Comment: @perigrin How would you use `duck_type` here?  I tried to understand the feature from `Moose` docs, but still don't quite follow.

Comment: @bvr Perhaps he meant something like `has _so => (is => 'ro', isa => duck_type('Set::Object',\@methods), lazy_build => 1);` ?

Comment: @Hartmut Behrens - I don't think so, this was exactly what I was trying to avoid using the regex (i.e. extract list of methods from `isa` class and avoid listing them explicitly).

Comment: @bvr: I was actually replying to Oesor rather than you. If you're building a list of methods, use a DuckType. This means you can re-use it in lots of other places and get all of Moose's type checking framework to go with you. It also allows better polymorphism. However regex delegation like that is frowned upon because it means that you could potentially end up blowing yourself up later during a refactor. Moose is pretty smart and my checking just now caught all the major cases I thought would bite you, but it's still a code smell in my book

Comment: @perigrin - Thanks a lot for explanation, I thought I misunderstood ducktype concept. I never used regex delegation in my code, but I was thinking that this way it provides all interface as inheritance did (if `Set::Object` got some new method, you would have it too). But apperently there are more problems that I haven't foreseen -- Moose is wonderful toolkit with great options, so it is sometimes difficult to see best practice.